# TypeError: Cannot read property 'CoinName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have these two reeors for my app and i added the code for each error. I cannot seem to figure out how to fixed both of these errors. With these two errors my app will not run. Any help as soon as possible would be awesome.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'CoinName' of undefined

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Tile } from "../Shared/Tile";
import { AppContext } from "../App/AppProvider";
import CoinImage from "../Shared/CoinImage";

export default function() {
  return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {({ currentFavorite, coinList }) => (
        <Tile>
          <SpotlightName> {coinList[currentFavorite].CoinName} </SpotlightName>
          <CoinImage spotlight coin={coinList[currentFavorite]} />
        </Tile>
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { AppContext } from "../App/AppProvider";
import PriceTile from "./PriceTile";

export default function() {
  return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {({ prices }) => (
        <PriceGrid>
          {Array.isArray(prices) && prices.map((price, index) => (
            <PriceTile key={`priceTile-${index}`} index={index} price={price} />
          ))}

        </PriceGrid>
      )}
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

AppProvider File below

```
import React from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import { async } from "q";
import moment from "moment";

// API call to CryptoCompare
const cc = require("cryptocompare");
// Set the Maximum amount of favorite coins
const MAX_FAVORITES = 10;
// used for historical function below
const TIME_UNITS = 10;

export const AppContext = React.createContext();

export class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Default states
    this.state = {
      page: "clocks",
      favorites: ["BTC", "LTC", "ETH", "DASH"],
      timeInterval: "[this.state.timeInterval]",
      ...this.savedSettings(),
      setPage: this.setPage,
      addCoin: this.addCoin,
      removeCoin: this.removeCoin,
      isInFavorites: this.isInFavorites,
      confirmFavorites: this.confirmFavorites,
      setCurrentFavorite: this.setCurrentFavorite,
      setFilteredCoins: this.setFilteredCoins,
      changeChartSelect: this.changeChartSelect
    };
  }
  // Whenever we mount this whole app component, we fetch the coins and thier prices
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchCoins();
    this.fetchPrices();
    this.fetchHistorical();
  };

  fetchCoins = async () => {
    let coinList = (await cc.coinList()).Data;
    this.setState({ coinList });
  };

  // async function
  fetchPrices = async () => {
    if (this.state.firstVisit) return;
    let prices = await this.prices();
    this.setState({ prices });
  };

  fetchHistorical = async () => {
    if (this.state.firstVisit) return;
    let results = await this.historical();
    let historical = [
      {
        name: this.state.currentFavorite,
        data: results.map((ticker, index) => [
          moment()
            .subtract({ [this.state.timeInterval]: TIME_UNITS - index })
            .valueOf(),
          ticker.USD
        ])
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ historical });
  };

  // this function supports fetchPrices above
  prices = async () => {
    let returnData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.favorites.length; i++) {
      try {
        let priceData = await cc.priceFull(this.state.favorites[i], "USD");
        returnData.push(priceData);
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn("Fetch price error: ", e);
      }
    }
    return returnData;
  };

  // this function supports fetchHistorical above
  historical = () => {
    let promises = [];
    for (let units = TIME_UNITS; units > 0; units--) {
      promises.push(
        cc.priceHistorical(
          this.state.currentFavorite,
          ["USD"],
          moment()
            .subtract({ [this.state.timeInterval]: units })
            .toDate()
        )
      );
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  };

  addCoin = key => {
    let favorites = [...this.state.favorites];
    if (favorites.length < MAX_FAVORITES) {
      favorites.push(key);
      this.setState({ favorites });
    }
  };

  removeCoin = key => {
    let favorites = [...this.state.favorites];
    this.setState({ favorites: _.pull(favorites, key) });
  };

  isInFavorites = key => _.includes(this.state.favorites, key);

  confirmFavorites = () => {
    let currentFavorite = this.state.favorites[0];
    this.setState(
      {
        firstVisit: false,
        page: "clocks",
        currentFavorite,
        prices: null,
        historical: null
      },
      () => {
        this.fetchPrices();
        this.fetchHistorical();
      }
    );
    localStorage.setItem(
      "blockclockDash",
      JSON.stringify({
        favorites: this.state.favorites,
        currentFavorite
      })
    );
  };

  // Set the localStorage to be a stringified object of our current value MERGED with our current Favorite selection
  setCurrentFavorite = sym => {
    this.setState(
      {
        currentFavorite: sym,
        historical: null
      },
      this.fetchHistorical
    );
    localStorage.setItem(
      "blockclockDash",
      JSON.stringify({
        ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blockclockDash")),
        currentFavorite: sym
      })
    );
  };

  savedSettings() {
    let blockclockDashData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blockclockDash"));
    if (!blockclockDashData) {
      return { page: "coin select", firstVisit: true };
    }
    let { favorites, currentFavorite } = blockclockDashData;
    return { favorites, currentFavorite };
  }

  setPage = page =>
    this.setState({
      page
    });

  setFilteredCoins = filteredCoins => this.setState({ filteredCoins });

  changeChartSelect = value => {
    this.setState(
      { timeInterval: value, historical: null },
      this.fetchHistorical
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your AppProvider and AppContext

Comment: What is the best way to share you that entire code?

Comment: Monika i added the AppProvider file to this

Comment: One reason might be that `coinList` gets a value once a fetch is done. So at first, your consumer will get `null`. I guess you should try to give initial values to `coinList` and `currentFavorite` to avoid that error (try logging those two values in the context consumer might confirm my assumption => you'll get `null` first and values after)

Answer (score 0):

A naive way to avoid that error would be to check first if the two values are not `null`:

```
export default function() {
  return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
      {({ currentFavorite, coinList }) => (
       (coinList && currentFavorite) ?
       <Tile>
          <SpotlightName> {coinList[currentFavorite].CoinName} </SpotlightName>
          <CoinImage spotlight coin={coinList[currentFavorite]} />
        </Tile>
       : <div>Loading... </div>
      )
      }
    </AppContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Glad it works ! Do not hesitate to validate n'y answer then 